# CSS Selector fails to change style

Tags: html, css

I have this css code for an Angular mat-group-button

```
mat-button-toggle-group mat-button-toggle button div.mat-button-toggle-label-content {    
  line-height: 0px;
}
```

This is the generated code

```
<mat-button-toggle-group _ngcontent-sah-c203="" role="group" name="os_attribution" aria-label="Atribuição de OS"
  class="mat-button-toggle-group mat-button-toggle-group-appearance-standard" ng-reflect-name="os_attribution"
  aria-disabled="false">
  <mat-button-toggle _ngcontent-sah-c203="" value="anyone"
    class="mat-button-toggle mat-button-toggle-appearance-standard" ng-reflect-value="anyone" tabindex="-1"
    id="mat-button-toggle-2"><button type="button" class="mat-button-toggle-button mat-focus-indicator"
      id="mat-button-toggle-2-button" tabindex="0" aria-pressed="false" name="os_attribution">
      <div class="mat-button-toggle-label-content">
        <mat-icon _ngcontent-sah-c203="" role="img" class="mat-icon notranslate material-icons mat-icon-no-color"
          aria-hidden="true">assignment_turned_in</mat-icon>
          Atribuídas 
      </div>
    </button>
   </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

I am able to change the style of the elements until this selection

```
mat-button-toggle-group mat-button-toggle { 
  background: red;
}
```

But after that, when I reach button, nothing I've tried works

What's happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're using angular right?
In this case the problem is about view encapsulation.
If you check the generated styles, you notice that they are scoped to the parent components assigned ID.
To opt out of the view encapsulation you can use the `::ng-deep` selector.

```
::ng-deep mat-button-toggle-group mat-button-toggle button div.mat-button-toggle-label-content {    
  line-height: 0px;
}
```

Comment: ding ding ding winner, but only if I said !important, if not my suggestion just appears scratched.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use the CSS class selector `.`!

```css
.mat-button-toggle-group .mat-button-toggle { 
  background: red;
}
```

If any of those are angular components, you cannot be sure that they will build into the same HTML tag names. Its better to use classes if it involves non-standard tag names (stuff that isn't `button`, `div`, `span`, etc).

Comment: mat-button-toggle-group and mat-button-toggle are elements in my HTML snippet

Answer (score 0):

`mat-button-toggle` is missing the period. Needs to be `.mat-button-toggle`.

Comment: The answer is incorrect. You can style CSS elements by specifying the tag. This problem is about view encapsulation

Comment: Yep... just noticed that it was also the html element. Only saw the class name, which is identical the tag name. My bad.